# Python sqlite3 SQL query Get all entries with newest date but limit per single unique column

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called 'fileEvents'. It has four columns (there are more but not relevant to the question): id, fileId, action and time.

The same fileId, action and time values can appear in multiple rows.

The query I want is simple but I can't think of a working one: Get the latest entry since a specific time for every fileId.

I tried the following.

First I will try to just get all entries sorted by time since a specific time:

```
SELECT * FROM `fileEvents` ORDER BY `time` DESC WHERE `time` < 1000
```

The result is of course fine (`id`, `action`, `fileId`, `time`):

```
[(6, 0, 3, 810), (5, 0, 3, 410), (2, 0, 1, 210), (3, 0, 2, 210), (4, 0, 3, 210), (1, 0, 1, 200)]
```

So it is all sorted. But now I only want unique fileId`s. So I add a GROUP BY`fileId`:

```
SELECT * FROM `fileEvents` GROUP BY `fileId` ORDER BY `time` DESC WHERE `time` < 1000
```

Which of course is wrong. Because first it will group the results and then sort them, but they are already grouped so there is no sorting:

```
[(3, 0, 2, 210), (4, 0, 3, 210), (1, 0, 1, 200)]
```

When I try to reverse the GROUP BY and ORDER BY, I get a OperationalError: near "GROUP": syntax error

Also when I try to do a sub query where I first get the sorted list and then group them the result is wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM `fileEvents` WHERE `id` IN (
SELECT `id` FROM `fileEvents` ORDER BY `time` DESC WHERE `time` < 1000
) GROUP BY `fileId`
```

With the (wrong) result:

```
[(1, 0, 1, 200), (3, 0, 2, 210), (4, 0, 3, 210)]
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
[(6, 0, 3, 810), (2, 0, 1, 210), (3, 0, 2, 210)]
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could get the result I want? What am I missing?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select * -- replace * with the columns that you want in the result
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by fileid order by time desc) rn
  from fileevents 
  where time < 1000
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical solution to this top-1-per-group problem is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select fe.* 
from fileevents fe
where fe.time = (
    select max(fe1.time) 
    from fileevents fe1 
    where fe1.fileid = fe.fileid and fe1.time < 1000
)
```

For performance with this query, you want an index on `(fileid, time)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works like a charm! I never heard of correlated subqueries. I will look into it.

Comment: A little note to this answer: When working with a few number of rows it was fine. But the executing time grows quickly when I fill the table with more than 100k entries.

The solution of forpass does execute 136x (!) faster in my case, with the same result.